# max() functions

Tags: sql, max

I create the following table.

```
create table man(id integer, name varchar(20), city varchar(20), age integer)
```

I want to find the name of the person with maximum age.

So, I ran following query,

```
select name, max(age) from man group by name;
```

It shows name of all person in ascending order with their age. What is going wrong?

Comment: What does man actually contain? What is the maximum age of a person? I only know people with a single age at once.

Comment: Seems I finally figured out what you were asking for. Trying to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to obtain the person with the greater age, you can do :

```
select name, age from man order by age desc limit 1;
```

For a query working with SQL Server :

```
select top 1 name, age from man order by age desc;
```

Your query is doing something else. `max` uses your `group` clause to do its computation. Since you're grouping by name, `max(age)` is the maximal age for people with the same name.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. It shows the error like "SQL not recognized 'LIMIT' ". That means, SQL Server doesn't support 'LIMIT'.

Answer (score 1):

I struggle to understand what you're doing here. A person can have more than a single age in your model?

Anyway. If you want the maximum age in the table `man`, you need to run:

```
select max(age) from man
```

Now who is this? If you add `name` to the query, the DB engine will return all names (since you asked for all of them, not a specific one; grouping won't help since most names will already be distince) combined with the max. value of the `age` column.

What you need is a subquery:

```
select m1.name
from man m1
where m1.age = (
    select max(m2.age)
    from man m2
)
```

This selects all elements where the age is the same as the highest age in the set.

Answer (score 0):

For each name it's giving you the maximum age of all the people with that name.  (That's what you asked for, isn't it?)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It shows each name with maximum age with that name.

Answer (score 0):

select name. max(age) from man gruop by name;

Should be

SELECT name, max(age) FROM man GROUP BY name;

You could also try

SELECT name, age FROM man ORDER BY age DESC

Maybe a little more information about the results you were expecting would be helpfull?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT NAME, AGE
    FROM MAN
GROUP BY NAME, AGE
  HAVING AGE = (SELECT MAX (AGE) FROM MAN)
```